# Use gmail-tester attachment data (PDF) with pdf-lib

Tags: javascript, pdf

pdf-lib I am using [gmail-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmail-tester) to pull down emails and I want to make PDF attachments into strings with [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/)

If I log out what I am getting back from email-tester for a PDF attachment it looks like:

```
        data: 'JVBERi0xLjYKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iagoKPDwKL1N1YnR5cGUgL0Zvcm0KL1R5cGUgL1hPYmplY3QKL01hdHJpeCBbMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdCi9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMgCjw8Ci9Db2xvclNwYWNlIAo8PAovRGVmYXVsdFJHQiAyIDAgUgo-PgovRXh0R1N0YXRlIAo8PAovR1MxIAo8PAovb3AgdHJ1ZQo-Pgo-PgovUHJvY1NldCBbL1BERiAvVGV4dCAvSW1hZ2VCIC9JbWFnZUMgL0ltYWdlSV0KL0ZvbnQgCjw8Ci9GMSAzIDAgUgo-PgovWE9iamVjdCAKPDwKL0ltMSA0IDAgUgovSW0yIDUgMCBSCi9JbTAgNiAwIFIKPj4KPj4KL0xlbmd0aCAxODM3Ci9CQm94IFswIDAgMjg1IDUwMF0KPj4Kc3RyZWFtCnENcQ0yODUgMCAwIDUwMCAwIDAgY20NcQ1CVA03IFRyDS9GMSAxLjAgVGYNMC4yNDE3NSAwLjA0MTgwIC0wLjA3MzMzIDAuMTM3ODAgMC4wMDA1OCAwLjQ4NzEyIFRtDTAuMDAwMDAgLTAuODQyMjcgVGQNKFwwMDBcMDY1KSBUag0vRjEgMS4wIFRmDTAuMjQxNzUgMC4wNDE4MCAtMC4wNzMzMyAwLjEzNzgwIDAuMDAwNTggMC40ODcxMiBUbQ0wLjU0MDUzIC0wLjg0MjI3IFRkDShcMDAwXDA0MykgVGoNL0YxIDEuMCBUZg0wLjI0MTc1IDAuMDQxODAgLTAuMDczMzMgMC4xMzc4MCAwLjAwMDU4IDAuNDg3MTIgVG0NMS4yMzE5MyAtMC44NDIyNyBUZA0oXDAwMFwwNTcpIFRqDS9GMSAxLjAgVGYNMC4yNDE3NSAwLjA0MTgwIC0wLjA3MzMzIDAuMTM3ODAgMC4wMDA1OCAwLjQ4NzEyIFRtDTEuOTk0MTQgLTAuODQyMjcgVGQNKFwwMDBcMDYyKSBUag0vRjEgMS4wIFRmDTAuMjQxNzUgMC4wNDE4MCAtMC4wNzMzMyAwLjEzNzgwIDAuMDAwNTggMC40ODcxMiBUbQ0yLjY0OTkwIC0wLjg0MjI3IFRkDShcMDAwXDA1NikgVGoNL0YxIDEuMCBUZg0wLjI0MTc1IDAuMDQxODAgLTAuMDczMzMgMC4xMzc4MCAwLjAwMDU4IDAuNDg3MTIgVG0NMy4yMjYwNyAtMC44NDIyNyBUZA0oXDAwMFwwNDcpIFRqDUVUDS9JbTAgRG8NUQ1xDUJUDTcgVHINL0YxIDEuMCBUZg0wLjI0MTc1IDAuMDQxODAgLTAuMDczMzMgMC4xMzc4MCAwLjAwMDU4IDAuMTM3MTIgVG0NMCAtMC44NDIyNyBUZA0oXDAwMFwwNjUpIFRqDS9GMSAxLjAgVGYNMC4yNDE3NSAwLjA0MTgwIC0wLjA3MzMzIDAuMTM3ODAgMC4wMDA1OCAwLjEzNzEyIFRtDTAuNTQwNTMgLTAuODQyMjcgVGQNKFwwMDBcMDQzKSBUag0vRjEgMS4wIFRmDTAuMjQxNzUgMC4wNDE4MCAtMC4wNzMzMyAwLjEzNzgwIDAuMDAwNTggMC4xMzcxMiBUbQ0xLjIzMTkzIC0wLjg0MjI3IFRkDShcMDAwXDA1NykgVGoNL0YxIDEuMCBUZg0wLjI0MTc1IDAuMDQxODAgLTAuMDczMzMgMC4xMzc4MCAwLjAwMDU4IDAuMTM3MTIgVG0NMS45OTQxNCAtMC44NDIyNyBUZA0oXDAwMFwwNjIpIFRqDS9GMSAxLjAgVGYNMC4yNDE3NSAwLjA0MTgwIC0wLjA3MzMzIDAuMTM3ODAgMC4wMDA1OCAwLjEzNzEyIFRtDTIuNjQ5OTAgLTAuODQyMjcgVGQNKFwwMDBcMDU2KSBUag0vRjEgMS4wIFRmDTAuMjQxNzUgMC4wNDE4MCAtMC4wNzMzMyAwLjEzNzgwIDAuMDAwNTggMC4xMzcxMiBUbQ0zLjIyNjA3IC0wLjg0MjI3IFRkDShcMDAwXDA0NykgVGoNRVQNL0ltMSBEbw1RDXENQlQNNyBUcg0vRjEgMS4wIFRmDTAuMjQxNzUgMC4wNDE4MCAtMC4wNzMzMyAwLjEzNzgwIDAuMDAwNTggMC44MzExMiBUbQ0wLjAwMDAwIC0wLjg0MjI3IFRkDShcMDAwXDA2NSkgVGoNL0YxIDEuMCBUZg0wLjI0MTc1IDAuMDQxODAgLTAuMDczMzMgMC4xMzc4MCAwLjAwMDU4IDAuODMxMTIgVG0NMC41NDA1MyAtMC44NDIyNyBUZA0oXDAwMFwwNDMpIFRqDS9GMSAxLjAgVGYNMC4yNDE3NSAwLjA0MTgwIC0wLjA3MzMzIDAuMTM3ODAgMC4wMDA1OCAwLjgzMTEyIFRtDTEuMjMxOTMgLTAuODQyMjcgVGQNKFwwMDBcMDU3KSBUag0vRjEgMS4wIFRmDTAuMjQxNzUgMC4wNDE4MCAtMC4wNzMzMyAwLjEzNzgwIDAuMDAwNTggMC44MzExMiBUbQ0xLjk5NDE0IC0wLjg0MjI3IFRkDShcMDAwXDA2MikgVGoNL0YxIDEuMCBUZg0wLjI0MTc1IDAuMDQxODAgLTAuMDczMzMgMC4xMzc4MCAwLjAwMDU4IDAuODMxMTIgVG0NMi42NDk5MCAtMC44NDIyNyBUZA0oXDAwMFwwNTYpIFRqDS9GMSAxLjAgVGYNMC4yNDE3NSAwLjA0MTgwIC0wLjA3MzMzIDAuMTM3ODAgMC4wMDA1OCAwLjgzMTEyIFRtDTMuMjI2MDcgLTAuODQyMjcgVGQNKFwwMDBcMDQ3KSBUag1FVA0vSW0yIERvDVENDVENUQ0KZW5kc3RyZWFtIAplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKWy9JQ0NCYXNlZCA3IDAgUl0KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCgo8PAovTmFtZSAvRjEKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUwCi9CYXNlRm9udCAvV1RVVExSK09sZFN0YW1wZXIKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9JZGVudGl0eS1ICi9EZXNjZW5kYW50Rm9udHMgWzggMCBSXQovVG9Vbmljb2RlIDkgMCBSCj4-CmVuZG9iagoKNCAwIG9iagoKPDwKL05hbWUgL1gKL0RlY29kZVBhcm1zIAo8PAovSFNhbXBsZXMgWzEgMSAxIDFdCi9Db2x1bW5zIDI4NQovUm93cyA1MDAKL0NvbG9ycyAzCi9WU2FtcGxlcyBbMSAxIDEgMV0KL1FGYWN0b3IgMC4wCi9CbGVuZCAxCi9Db2xvclRyYW5zZm9ybSAxCj4-Ci9CaXRzUGVyQ29tcG9uZW50IDgKL0xlbmd0aCAxMDc5OAovQ29sb3JTcGFjZSAvRGV2aWNlUkdCCi9JbnRlbnQgL1JlbGF0aXZlQ29sb3JpbWV0cmljCi9IZWlnaHQgNTAwCi9TdWJ0eXBlIC9JbWFnZQovRmlsdGVyIC9EQ1REZWNvZGUKL1R5cGUgL1hPYmplY3QKL1dpZHRoIDI4NQovU01hc2sgMTAgMCBSCj4-CnN0cmVhbQr_2P_uAA5BZG9iZQBkgAAAAAH_2wCEAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf_AABEIAfQBHQMBEQACEQEDEQH_xAGiAAAABgIDAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCAYFBAkDCgIBAAsBAAAGAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAYFBAMHAggBCQAKCxAAAgEDBAEDAwIDAwMCBgl1AQIDBBEFEgYhBxMiAAgxFEEyIxUJUUIWYSQzF1JxgRhikSVDobHwJjRyChnB0TUn4VM2gvGSokRUc0VGN0djKFVWVxqywtLi8mSDdJOEZaOzw9PjKThm83UqOTpISUpYWVpnaGlqdnd4eXqFhoeIiYqUlZaXmJmapKWmp6ipqrS1tre4ubrExcbHyMnK1NXW19jZ2uTl5ufo6er09fb3-Pn6EQACAQMCBAQDBQQEBAYGBW0BAgMRBCESBTEGACITQVEHMmEUcQhCgSORFVKhYhYzCbEkwdFDcvAX4YI0JZJTGGNE8aKyJjUZVDZFZCcKc4OTRnTC0uLyVWV1VjeEhaOzw9Pj8ykalKS0xNTk9JWltcXV5fUoR1dmOHaGlqa2xtbm9md3h5ent8fX5_dIWGh4iJiouMjY6Pg5SVlpeYmZqbnJ2en5KjpKWmp6ipqqusra6vr_2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA_AN_j37r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvde9-691737r3Xvfuvd'... 452952 more characters,
        filename: 'MISC.pdf',
        mimeType: 'application/pdf'
```

I have been trying to pass this data pdf-lib into using either:

```
        var byteCharacters = atob(data);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  
        this.document = await pdfLib.getDocument([byteArray]).promise
```

or just:

```
this.document = await pdfLib.getDocument({data}).promise
```

Both of these result in errors indicating the PDF is malformed.  Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Oh,  looks like it works if I use an older version of pdf-lib

```
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.3.200",
```

and do:

```
        this.document = await pdfLib.getDocument(Buffer.from(data, 'base64')).promise
```

then it works.